How to track contour ordering in a four-point function with fermionic operators?
This is a 2d free fermion theory related question.
I'm working on calculating a four point function with operator insertions at z=0, 1, 3/2, $\infty$. Each of operator is dual to states constructed by acting fermionic modes ($\psi_{-\frac{1}{2}}, \psi_{-\frac{3}{2}},...$) on the NS vacuum.
I would like to rewrite these operators in terms of the contour integrals, e.g.
\begin{equation}
\psi_{-\frac{1}{2}}|0>= \oint \psi(z) dz 
\end{equation}
Afterwards, to compute the correlation function, my approach involves two steps:

Calculate the correlation function for the free fermions using the two-dimensional bosonization formula.

Perform the contour integrals.


My question pertains to the first step: since there are multiple contours centered around
z=0,1,
2
3
​
,$\infty$, how do I keep track of the ordering of these contours with respect to
z=0?
